# No Response on NGINX when using upstream

Tags: nginx, http-headers, proxypass, nginx-location

I'm trying to load balance a web application through nginx, It works fine for all will my web application calls a service with sub-path.

for example it works

```
http://example.com/luna/
```

but not for

```
 http://example.com/luna/sales
```

My nginx.conf

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  auto;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

     map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream lunaups {
        server myhostserver1.com:8080;
        server myhostserver2.com:8080;
    }


    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;

        proxy_pass_header Server;

        location = / {
             rewrite ^ http://example.com/luna redirect;
         }

        location /luna {
            rewrite ^$/luna/(.*)/^ /$1 redirect;
            proxy_pass http://lunaups;
            #add_header  X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

my web application calls a service with additional subpath like /luna/sales  fails to return response. What am i missing here?

It works if i remove one of my host server from upstream, But when I add second host on upstream it fails to return response.

Is my rewrite rule wrong or my configurations as whole is wrong?

Comment: What is `^$/luna/(.*)/^` supposed to do? It seems to have a spurious `$` and a spurious `^`.

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm new to nginx, i've constructed this myself seeing the document, Just working trial and error, Please correct me if possible.

Comment: Is it supposed to knock off the `/luna` prefix from the URI before sending it upstream?

Comment: No, My web application runs on http://example.com/luna and all its backend service requests are made internally with muti-path additions (eg:http://example.com/luna/sales). Those services are not working with above configurations.

Comment: So, what is `^$/luna/(.*)/^` supposed to do? I am trying to understand your requirement.

Comment: It should allow all my request and response from /luna & its subsequent multipath /luna/* (right now my /luna/sales is not returning any response).

Answer (score 0):

There are four suffixes to the `rewrite` directive and they all have specific uses. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

If you want the URI `/` to be mapped to `/luna` without changing the URL in the browser, you would use an internal rewrite with `rewrite ... last`. For example:

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /luna last;
}
```

In the `location /luna` block, you need to rewrite the URI before sending it to `proxy_pass` statement (without leaving the location block), which requires a `rewrite ... break`. For example:

```
location /luna {
    rewrite ^/luna(/.*)$ $1 break;
    rewrite ^ / break;
    proxy_pass http://lunaups;
}
```

The first rewrite changes any URI with a sub-path, and the second rewrite handles the URI without a sub-path.

See [this useful resource](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html) on regular expressions.

Comment: Hi Richard, Now I'm able to see the request triggered to /luna/sales in nginx access logs, but still I can't see response in client, The Http status code seems to be 200 OK on nginx log. The chrome Developer tools' network tab shows No response as well.